# How to turn Win11 taskbar entirely black?

Tags: taskbar, colors, windows-11, color-theme

Windows 11 has a dark mode and a custom color picker for the taskbar. But both won't turn it totally black. It always keeps this blackish-grey collor accent, even if you pull the custom color slider to totally black.

Is there a way to disable this and make the taskbar turn entirely black?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done in *Settings > Personalization > Colors*.

Turn the Transparency effects to `Off` in order to see the taskbar and
Start/search in black color:

[image]

For more information see the article
[How To Make Windows 11 Taskbar Black (Without Dark Mode)](https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-make-windows-11-taskbar-black-without-dark-mode/).

EDIT: Reports say that this has stopped working for the latest
Windows 11 version.

Comment: I already have these settings. But the taskbar is still black-ish-grey. My background picture is entirely black and I wanted those colors to match (if that's even possible)

Comment: I don't know what else you could do beside setting the taskbar to real black color and with no transparency. You could complain to Microsoft via the Feedback Hub, and wait for a workaround (unfortunately I don't know of any).

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has 2 up votes. This transparency setting simply has no effect on the taskbar of Windows 11. The taskbar background color is defined in the current theme. Windows 11 has a dark and a light theme. The colors are defined in the file C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\Aero\areo.msstyles. You cannot easily change these colors.

Comment: @Elmue: Windows is changing, what worked yesterday is not guaranteed to work today. There have lately been some changes in Windows 11 that invalidated many solutions, not only this one. I added your remark in my answer.

Comment: I have Windows 11 build 22000. Which one did you write this answer for?

Comment: @Elmue: Build numbers are not everything. Windows 11 updates itself regularly without changing the build number. Only major upgrades change it.

Comment: So you say that on your Windows 11 the transparency setting has any effect on the color of the taskbar? I can only tell that my taskbar has always the same color 0x202020 for the dark theme and 0xF3F3F3 for the light theme. It is not translucent anymore like in Windows 10 and is not affected by the background image behind it. It is completly opaque and no setting changes its color.

Comment: @Elmue: It worked at the time my answer was written. I don't know how to make it work once it doesn't any more.